# PHP preg_match double quote matching

Tags: php, regex, double, double-quotes

I'm a newbie, and a bit of a regex dullard, so please forgive me what will appear to be a completely stupid question.

In PHP I'm trying to use a regex to match when a double quote " appears in text from a control on an HTML form and allow it to be used. The current regex isn't working:

```
preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \"\'\?\-]/', $v)
```

as all the other characters work ok, but if I put a " in the text, it still fails the regex.

I've tried `[^a-zA-Z0-9 \"\'\?\-]` on https://regex101.com/, and it seems to work ok. Is there something wrong with my PHP instance that needs fixing, or is PHP in some way not working consistently with https://regex101.com/?

Ian J.

Edit:

Input: test"

Output: 10

Edit:

```
$v = test"
$n = 50
$s = Name:
$f = $fail (which is passed by reference as a counter)

function validate_text($v, $n, $s, &$f)
{
    if ($v == "")
    {
        ++$f;
        return "<span class='error'>".$s."</span>";
    }
    elseif ((strlen($v) > $n) || preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \"\'\?\-]/', $v))
    {
        ++$f;
        return "<span class='error'>".$s."</span>&nbsp;<span class='errorextra'>(Please enter only upper or lower case letters, numerals, spaces, and basic punctuation, maximum ".$n." characters)</span>";
    }
    return $s;
}
```

Edit: OK, it appears that there is something odd happening between the $_POST value and it's passing to a variable. I will have to investigate and get back. But for now, this question is on hold.

Edit: some initial investigation points to a conversion occuring in a call to htmlentities earlier in the code doing a conversion of the double quote to something else. Therefore I don't think this is a regex problem. I've marked 'beiller' as the answer due to his code example putting me on the path to finding where the problem actually is.

Comment: Original post edited for input/ouput

Comment: But to check for presence of `"` in `test"` you don't need regex. Use `strchr` or `strstr` functions

Comment: I'm using the regex for other things as well, not just "

Comment: You don't have to escape `"` by writing `\"` if you place your regex inside a single quoted string because `"` has no special meaning to the regex engine.

Comment: TiMESPLiNTER - OK, I just modified my regex to remove the escape, but the result is still the same.

Comment: edit to add PHP function code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing so let me describe what your regular expression does:

```
preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \"\'\?\-]/', $v)
```

It will match any string which DOES NOT contain `a-zA-Z0-9 \"\'\?\-`

Also you are escaping your `"` with `\"` which is not necessary. Try removing the back slash.

The input `test"` should not be matched by this regex because it contains the letter "t".

I made another attempt but answered too quickly. Try the following code:

```
$v = 'test"';
$n = 50;
$s = 'Name:';
$f = 0;

function validate_text($v, $n, $s, &$f)
{
    if ($v == "")
    {
        ++$f;
        return "<span class='error'>".$s."</span>";
    }
    elseif ((strlen($v) > $n) || preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 "\'\?\-]/', $v))
    {
        ++$f;
        return "<span class='error'>".$s."</span>&nbsp;<span class='errorextra'>(Please enter only upper or lower case letters, numerals, spaces, and basic punctuation, maximum ".$n." characters)</span>";
    }
    return $s;
}

echo validate_text($v, $n, $s, $f);
```

Output:

```
Name:
```

Comment: That's right, I'm trying to find any characters other than in the regex, and fail the input back to the user so they can't use them. I want them to be able to use ", but not $ or % or ^ or &, for example.

Comment: I tried `preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \"\'\?\-]+/', $v)` and it's still not working

Comment: The strlen check is for if the input value is over 50, which if so returns TRUE, which triggers the error. test" is only 5 characters, so returns FALSE and then the preg_match is checked.

Comment: Quoting the input values is not the way the function works, as the values are already strings coming in from a control via variables. However, I overrode the $v value to 'text"' within the function and it did pass the regex ok, so it seems something is wrong between the control on the form and the variable being passed into the function.

Comment: Yes it looks like your code works fine. The problem appears to be elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

this is a code am using and its working fine

```
function somefunc($value)
{
    $result= preg_replace("#[?.&,;\"\'@\-_ \/]#", " ", $value);
    return $result;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing about regexp is that they are looking for *any* substring of your subject that matches given pattern. So if you want to allow let say alphanum characters, space and double quote, look for everything that is *not* within your allowed characters, and negate the preg_match result.

```
var_dump(!preg_match('/[^[:alnum:] "]+/', 'lorem ipsum dolor si amet 42'));
=> bool(true)
var_dump(!preg_match('/[^[:alnum:] "]+/', 'lorem ipsum "dolor" si amet'));
=> bool(true)
var_dump(!preg_match('/[^[:alnum:] "]+/', 'lorem&ipsum "do^or" +si amet'));
=> bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this discussion having the similar problem: 
tried to match quotes, my regex was working ok in JavaScript section of the code and passed tests on https://regex101.com/, but didn't work properly in the php section.

Changing regex outside quotes from double to single and back, escaping or not quotes inside the regex – didn't make any difference.

The solution: I had the string filtered

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'my_var', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Removing the filter or adding the flag

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'my_var', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

solved the problem. So quotes in the string and quotes in the regex were not equal because of sanitising encoding. Hope it will save someones sleepless time :-)